# Single Positional Index Out-of-Bounds - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on dictionary of dataframes--five in total, and I am trying to grab the first row of each dataframe. My code appears to work for some of the dataframes, but not others.
The sample dataframes are below:

```
a0 = {'dataset': {'0.05, 1.0, 175': 'CS:1', '0.05, 1.0, 150': 'CS:1'},
 'mean_score': {'0.05, 1.0, 175': -0.2820450154520415,
  '0.05, 1.0, 150': -0.28204501545204186},
 'rank_score': {'0.05, 1.0, 175': 1, '0.05, 1.0, 150': 2},
 'std_score': {'0.05, 1.0, 175': 0.11499605607995111,
  '0.05, 1.0, 150': 0.11499605607995127},
 'contamination': {'0.05, 1.0, 175': 0.05, '0.05, 1.0, 150': 0.05},
 'max_samples': {'0.05, 1.0, 175': 1.0, '0.05, 1.0, 150': 1.0},
 'n_estimators': {'0.05, 1.0, 175': 175, '0.05, 1.0, 150': 150}}

a1 = {'dataset': {'0.05, 1.0, 200': 'CK:-1', '0.05, 1.0, 175': 'CK:-1'},
 'mean_score': {'0.05, 1.0, 200': -0.20618057780261195,
  '0.05, 1.0, 175': -0.20618057780261267},
 'rank_score': {'0.05, 1.0, 200': 1, '0.05, 1.0, 175': 2},
 'std_score': {'0.05, 1.0, 200': 0.13109535628226052,
  '0.05, 1.0, 175': 0.13109535628226013},
 'contamination': {'0.05, 1.0, 200': 0.05, '0.05, 1.0, 175': 0.05},
 'max_samples': {'0.05, 1.0, 200': 1.0, '0.05, 1.0, 175': 1.0},
 'n_estimators': {'0.05, 1.0, 200': 200, '0.05, 1.0, 175': 175}}

a2 = {'dataset': {'0.05, 0.7, 125': 'PH:1',
  '0.05, 0.7749999999999999, 200': 'PH:1'},
 'mean_score': {'0.05, 0.7, 125': -0.22096885360666768,
  '0.05, 0.7749999999999999, 200': -0.22416479620828117},
 'rank_score': {'0.05, 0.7, 125': 1, '0.05, 0.7749999999999999, 200': 2},
 'std_score': {'0.05, 0.7, 125': 0.05228492731122392,
  '0.05, 0.7749999999999999, 200': 0.061897704957581456},
 'contamination': {'0.05, 0.7, 125': 0.05,
  '0.05, 0.7749999999999999, 200': 0.05},
 'max_samples': {'0.05, 0.7, 125': 0.7,
  '0.05, 0.7749999999999999, 200': 0.7749999999999999},
 'n_estimators': {'0.05, 0.7, 125': 125, '0.05, 0.7749999999999999, 200': 200}}

a3 = {'dataset': {'0.05, 0.85, 125': 'PRT:-1',
  '0.05, 0.85, 100': 'PRT:-1'},
 'mean_score': {'0.05, 0.85, 125': -0.12896828405478034,
  '0.05, 0.85, 100': -0.13141635454748085},
 'rank_score': {'0.05, 0.85, 125': 1, '0.05, 0.85, 100': 2},
 'std_score': {'0.05, 0.85, 125': 0.016228240324984843,
  '0.05, 0.85, 100': 0.013178168219693726},
 'contamination': {'0.05, 0.85, 125': 0.05, '0.05, 0.85, 100': 0.05},
 'max_samples': {'0.05, 0.85, 125': 0.85, '0.05, 0.85, 100': 0.85},
 'n_estimators': {'0.05, 0.85, 125': 125, '0.05, 0.85, 100': 100}}

a4 = {'dataset': {'0.05, 1.0, 200': 'PRT:1',
  '0.05, 1.0, 175': 'PRT:1'},
 'mean_score': {'0.05, 1.0, 200': -0.1694053747115974,
  '0.05, 1.0, 175': -0.1694053747115976},
 'rank_score': {'0.05, 1.0, 200': 1, '0.05, 1.0, 175': 2},
 'std_score': {'0.05, 1.0, 200': 0.006550547930259526,
  '0.05, 1.0, 175': 0.006550547930259387},
 'contamination': {'0.05, 1.0, 200': 0.05, '0.05, 1.0, 175': 0.05},
 'max_samples': {'0.05, 1.0, 200': 1.0, '0.05, 1.0, 175': 1.0},
 'n_estimators': {'0.05, 1.0, 200': 200, '0.05, 1.0, 175': 175}}
```

The code to select row values based on the column is also shown below. The codes do work as expected for dataframes `a0 through a2`, but then with dataframes `a3 - a4`, I get the index positional error message.

```
subsets = ['CS:1', 'CK:-1', 'PH:1', 'PRT:-1', 'PRT:1']  # rows to select


#the code to retrieve the first rows for a0-a2 work as expected.
(a0.loc[a0['dataset'].isin([subsets[0]])].iloc[0][['contamination', 'max_samples', 'n_estimators']])

(a1.loc[a1['dataset'].isin([subsets[1]])].iloc[0][['contamination', 'max_samples', 'n_estimators']])

(a2.loc[a2['dataset'].isin([subsets[2]])].iloc[0][['contamination', 'max_samples', 'n_estimators']])

# the codes to retrieve the first frow for a3 - a4 give the single positional indexer is out-of-bounds error.
(a3.loc[a3['dataset'].isin([subsets[3]])].iloc[0][['contamination', 'max_samples', 'n_estimators']])

(a4.loc[a4['dataset'].isin([subsets[4]])].iloc[0][['contamination', 'max_samples', 'n_estimators']])
```

Not sure why, since I am not using an index that is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your samples, I cannot replicate the error. Anyhow, the "IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" in your code can only come from `.iloc[0]` which in turn can only produce this error, if there are no rows at all in the DataFrame it is used on. So the most likely cause of your error is the DataFrame not containing the string from the subsets list in the "dataset" column.

Comment: that's the strange part for me. The samples I shared are just the first two rows of the dataframes I am working with output as dictionaries. I think figured it out, for some reason. The index order of dataframes `a3 and a4`,  are switched in the code, so basically `iloc[0]`  in dataframes `a3 and a4` are searching in the wrong dataframes. Thanks.